# Debbuging Xamarin on Visual Studio Android O (API 26)

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-8.0-oreo

I've just update my OP3 on Android O, and I'm facing an issue while I want to test my Xamarin Forms app: 
The generation work, and I can install the APK with the command : `adb install -r`

But if I want to debbug the app in Visual Studio I've got this error :

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_ALREADY_EXISTS: Attempt to re-install Mono.Android.DebugRuntime without first uninstalling.]`

(Compilation set to API 25)

Any idea ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I can reproduce the same error, there are a few things you can do.

In your Android solution you can go to `Project`> `Properties` > `Android Options` and disable `Use Shared Runtime`. However deploying your app will take a very long time using this method.

You can also downgrade your phone to Nougat, which worked for me.

Let's hope OnePlus fixes this in the future.